# Проблема с ajax запросом (status code error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xhr

```
function get_users ()
{
    let users;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://blog.good-electric.ru/config/users.php",
        method: "GET",
        complete: function(xhr, status) { console.log(status, xhr); }
    }).done(function (data) {
        users = data;
    });
    return users;
}
```

complete возвращает status_code - error, подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка?

Comment: _подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка?_ - без точного текста ошибки нельзя сказать. Либо на сервере, либо не клиенте :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваша функция `get_users` асинхронная, а это значит, что переменная `users` в ней при `return`, всегда будет `undefined`.

Сделать функцию синхронной можно несколькими способами.

**Методом конструктора Promise:**

```js
function get_users() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://blog.good-electric.ru/config/users.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: resolve,
        error: reject
      })
    })
}

get_users()
.then(data => console.log('success', data))
.catch(err => console.log('err', err))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Методом `callback`-а:**

```js
function get_users(success, error) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://blog.good-electric.ru/config/users.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: success,
    error: error
  })
}

get_users(data => {
  consoe.log('success', data)
}, err => {
  console.log('err', err)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: но ведь в вопросе спрашивается про вывод console.log: `complete: function(xhr, status) { console.log(status, xhr); }` который выводит `status_code - error`

Comment: если бы вопрос был про значение `users`, то стоило бы проголосовать за закрытие в качестве дубликата: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/186999)

Comment: функция `get_users` сама по себе не будет работать, если не решить вопрос с асинхронностью. А ошибка может возникать из-за `CORS`

Comment: get_users - сама по себе отлично работает. И судя по тому, что приходит статус - скорее всего ошибка на сервере, а не cors, но без текста ошибки ничего нельзя сказать, возможно это попытка привести невалидный json к объекту упала

Comment: _Сделать функцию синхронной можно несколькими способами_ - ни один из приведенных способов **НЕ** делает функцию синхронной

Comment: @Grundy return не может работать, как изначально планировал автор, поскольку, как и писал я в своем ответе, return возвращает undefined

Comment: и мы возвращаемся к тому, что вопрос совсем не об этом. А если бы был об этом, то просто стоило проголосовать за дубликат.

Comment: возможно, но это не делает мой ответ неверным. как найти дубликат?

Comment: Делает :-) потому что он не отвечает на поставленный вопрос. И если бы не объем, то можно было бы преобразовать его в комментарий.

Comment: он отвечает на вопрос, который придет по решению текущего вопроса - а не прийти он не может

Comment: Вот когда придет - тогда и надо будет его решать.

Comment: как найти дубликат?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91157/discussion-between-grundy-and-mix).

Comment: если в вопросе ошибка, то нужно указать автору на нее, а не ждать, пока создастся новый вопрос. смысла в этом нету